# Get a list of JSON property names from a class to use in a query string

Tags: c#, json, json.net, .net-3.5, query-string

If I have a C# model class that is used by JSON.net to bind data from a serialized JSON string, is there a way that I can create a query string from that class in order to make the initial request?

Model class example:

```
public class model
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
   public long ID { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "some_string")]
   public string SomeString {get; set;} 
}
```

Querystring example:

```
baseUrl + uri + "&fields=id,some_string" + token
```

So the essence of what I am trying to do is gather both "id" and "some_string" from the model object so i can dynamically create a the "&fields" arguments. Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

@Leigh Shepperson has the right idea; however, you can do it with less code using LINQ.  I would create a helper method like this:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...

public static string GetFields(Type modelType)
{
    return string.Join(",",
        modelType.GetProperties()
                 .Select(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>())
                 .Select(jp => jp.PropertyName));
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var fields = "&fields=" + GetFields(typeof(model));
```

**EDIT**

If you're running under the 3.5 version of the .Net Framework such that you don't have the generic `GetCustomAttribute<T>` method available to you, you can do the same thing with the non-generic `GetCustomAttributes()` method instead, using it with `SelectMany` and `Cast<T>`:

```
    return string.Join(",",
        modelType.GetProperties()
                 .SelectMany(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute))
                                   .Cast<JsonPropertyAttribute>())
                 .Select(jp => jp.PropertyName)
                 .ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, this is a real elegant solution.

Comment: I should have specified better in the question, I'll update that after this meeting. I'm using Unity3D i.e. modified .net 3.5 and it seems like generic type was given to getcustomattributes in 4.5

Comment: Your question was originally tagged with `Unity3d`, but since the question did not seem to have anything to do with that, I removed it and added `Json.Net` in its place.  I've updated my answer to show how you can use the non-generic `GetCustomAttributes()` method to do the same thing in .NET 3.5.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Just had to add a .toArray() after the last select statement.

Comment: @CostelloNicho Good catch.  I missed that one.  I updated my answer with your fix.  Thanks for the accept!

Comment: I know this is old, but I just needed this and is great! However, Not all my properties have a `JsonPropertyAttribute` and I'm getting `null` exceptions. How can this `Linq` be modified to help that?

Comment: Ooo! I tested something and it worked. I hope it's ok that I modify the answer.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs - Your edit was not correct; it skipped the properties without `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "XXX")]` attributes rather than falling back on the c# property name.  You really should ask another question about this situation, but I added [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45829514/3744182) for what to do in such a situation.

Comment: @dbc, ah you're right. I guess I wasn't thinking about it, since it's what I wanted in the first place, but didn't think of other case-scenarios.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using reflection. This is the general idea:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    public class model
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public long ID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "some_string")]
        public string SomeString { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var model = new model();

            var result = string.Empty;

            PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(model).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
            {
                foreach (object attr in prop.GetCustomAttributes(true))
                {
                    result += (attr as JsonPropertyAttribute).PropertyName;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In cases where the model is only partially annotated with `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "XXX")]` attributes, or is annotated with [data contract attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm), or has [ignored](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) properties, you can use Json.NET's own [contract resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) to obtain the list of serialized property names.  First, introduce the following extension method:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static string [] PropertyNames(this IContractResolver resolver, Type type)
    {
        if (resolver == null || type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var contract = resolver.ResolveContract(type) as JsonObjectContract;
        if (contract == null)
            return new string[0];
        return contract.Properties.Where(p => !p.Ignored).Select(p => p.PropertyName).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then, do:

```
// Allocate the relevant contract resolver. 
// Options are CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() or DefaultContractResolver().
IContractResolver resolver = new DefaultContractResolver(); 

// Get properties
var propertyNames = resolver.PropertyNames(typeof(model));
var fields = "&fields=" + String.Join(",", propertyNames);
```

For `resolver` use [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm#CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver) if you are camel casing your property names (which ASP.NET Core Web API does [by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38139607)); otherwise use [`DefaultContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm).

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VfuMSN).

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm going to try to use this with my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45826000/getting-the-jsonpropertyattribute-of-a-property/

Answer (score 0):

A small variation of @Brian Rogers solution that solve null exception problem:

```
IEnumerable<string> props = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                                     .Select(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>())
                                     .Where(jp => jp != null)
                                     .Select(jp => jp.PropertyName);

string propsList = string.Join(',', props);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CreateContactProperties
{
   [JsonProperty("email")] public string email { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("firstname")] public string firstname { get; set; }
}

public string GetJsonPropertyFieldName(PropertyInfo t)
{
   var attr = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as JsonPropertyAttribute;

   return attr.PropertyName;
}


IList<PropertyInfo> entityprops = new List<PropertyInfo>(typeof(CreateContactProperties).GetProperties());
foreach (var item in entityprops)
{
  properties += $"{GetJsonPropertyFieldName(item)}, ";
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).