# asp.net core 1.0 web api use camelcase

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

On `RC2` the same code returns json format with camel case. After netcore 1.0 release i started new project and the same code is returning json in lowercase.

[image]

Tried multiple solutions but none of them were working
[web-api-serialize-properties-starting-from-lowercase-letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130431/web-api-serialize-properties-starting-from-lowercase-letter)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver
            = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
    });
```

This keeps a JSON object's name the same as .NET class property.

Comment: What namespace/references does this require.  There is no 'AddJsonOptions' that I'm able to see

Comment: Its MVC6.namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

    //     Extensions methods for configuring MVC via an Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IMvcBuilder.
class MvcJsonMvcBuilderExtensions

Comment: thanks  !! i have the same Problem this one work fine

Comment: Works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

You can configure JSON behavior this way:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
  {
      services.AddMvc()
                  .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                  {
                      options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                          new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                  });
  }
```

Comment: this actually now is the default behavior (unfortunately), he wanted Default, as is, no change in property names, case

Comment: @Omu These actually aren't the same (in .net core 2.0 anyway). The *DefaultContractResolver* will accept CamelCase and return TitleCase, the *CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver* accepts and returns CamelCase.

Comment: @Omu has this changed from .net core 1.x to 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this at the individual serializer level, instead of at the global level.

For example, to return an object as JSON on a controller action method you can do this:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() };

return new JsonResult(myObject, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

And the resulting JSON string will be in the expected PascalCase to match the .NET class/properties names