# Cannot Convert From JValue to JObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I have the following class with a static method in it,

```
public static class RouteSerializer
{
    public static string SerializeRouteInformation(string content)
    {
        RouteMapModel routeMapModel = new RouteMapModel();
        List<RouteMapModel.end_location> endLocationList = new List<RouteMapModel.end_location>();

        var obj = JObject.Parse(content);

        string objRoutes = obj["routes"].ToString();

        JArray routeArray = JArray.Parse(objRoutes);

        JArray legArray = new JArray();
        foreach (JObject item in routeArray)
        {
            string leg = item.GetValue("legs").ToString();                
            legArray.Add(leg);
        }

        JArray stepArray = new JArray();
        foreach (JObject item in legArray)
        {
            string step = item.GetValue("steps").ToString();
            stepArray.Add(step);
        }

        foreach(JObject item in stepArray)
        {
            string endLocation = item.GetValue("end_location").ToString();
            var serializedEndLocation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RouteMapModel.end_location>(endLocation);
            endLocationList.Add(serializedEndLocation);
        }

        //... goes on
    }
}
```

But, I got an Error on the begging of the second `foreach` as it says `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue cannot be assigned to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`. But the problem is, if I changed item type from JObject to JValue on the latter `foreach` clauses, I cannot be able to reach `.GetValue()` method as JValue doesn't inclued a one.

Below is the JSON string that I'm playing on,

```
    { "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ5cGzCGa4yhQRk-lsJUoyizk",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJb5VnEF64yhQRCrgps2g77jc",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
"routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 40.990381,
               "lng" : 29.0282547
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 40.9863897,
               "lng" : 29.0216118
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Harita verileri ©2019 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "0,9 km",
                  "value" : 894
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "11 dakika",
                  "value" : 655
               },
               "end_address" : "Caferağa Mahallesi, Tuğlacı Eminbey Cd. No:5, 34710 Kadıköy/İstanbul, Türkiye",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 40.9863897,
                  "lng" : 29.0218105
               },
               "start_address" : "Osmanağa Mahallesi, Serasker Cd. No:118, 34714 Kadıköy/İstanbul, Türkiye",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 40.9893375,
                  "lng" : 29.028225
               },
               "steps" : [
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "8 m",
                        "value" : 8
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 dakika",
                        "value" : 5
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.9894537,
                        "lng" : 29.0282117
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "\u003cb\u003eZiya Bey Sk.\u003c/b\u003e adlı yerden \u003cb\u003eSerasker Cd.\u003c/b\u003e hedefine \u003cb\u003ekuzey\u003c/b\u003e yönünde ilerleyin",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "kvdyFkqdpDGCMA?F"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.9893375,
                        "lng" : 29.028225
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,3 km",
                        "value" : 326
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "4 dakika",
                        "value" : 215
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.990381,
                        "lng" : 29.024582
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "\u003cb\u003eSerasker Cd.\u003c/b\u003e yönünde \u003cb\u003esola\u003c/b\u003e dönün",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "awdyFiqdpDMxAKr@OjACP[vCEPC^Cf@CLAHENMZ@LQf@Qd@KZENSj@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.9894537,
                        "lng" : 29.0282117
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "34 m",
                        "value" : 34
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 dakika",
                        "value" : 25
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.9901185,
                        "lng" : 29.0243691
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "\u003cb\u003eMühürdar Cd.\u003c/b\u003e yönünde \u003cb\u003esola\u003c/b\u003e dönün",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "{|dyFszcpDHFHF^X"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.990381,
                        "lng" : 29.024582
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "8 m",
                        "value" : 8
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 dakika",
                        "value" : 5
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.990081,
                        "lng" : 29.0242851
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "\u003cb\u003eMühürdar Cd.\u003c/b\u003e yönünde hafif \u003cb\u003esağa\u003c/b\u003e yönelin",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "g{dyFiycpD?D?@?@@??@DB"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.9901185,
                        "lng" : 29.0243691
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "7 m",
                        "value" : 7
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 dakika",
                        "value" : 6
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.9900274,
                        "lng" : 29.0243112
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "\u003cb\u003eMuvakkıthane Cd.\u003c/b\u003e konumunda \u003cb\u003esola\u003c/b\u003e dönün",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "_{dyFyxcpDDABA"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.990081,
                        "lng" : 29.0242851
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,4 km",
                        "value" : 352
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "4 dakika",
                        "value" : 259
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.987586,
                        "lng" : 29.0217648
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "\u003cb\u003eMühürdar Cd.\u003c/b\u003e yönünde \u003cb\u003esağa\u003c/b\u003e dönün",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "uzdyF}xcpDhAz@pA|@pBtAHRJHRPPNPX\\d@BDHKfAlBDLDHDN@LBN"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.9900274,
                        "lng" : 29.0243112
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "63 m",
                        "value" : 63
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 dakika",
                        "value" : 51
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.987087,
                        "lng" : 29.0216118
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "\u003cb\u003eMühürdar Cd.\u003c/b\u003e boyunca ilerlemek için \u003cb\u003esola\u003c/b\u003e dönün",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "mkdyF_icpDNBJ@J@TBJ?JADA@DDN"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.987586,
                        "lng" : 29.0217648
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "74 m",
                        "value" : 74
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 dakika",
                        "value" : 64
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.9864708,
                        "lng" : 29.0216118
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "\u003cb\u003eMühürdar Cd.\u003c/b\u003e boyunca ilerlemek için \u003cb\u003esola\u003c/b\u003e dönün",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "ihdyFahcpDJEJAFALAH?VBj@F"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.987087,
                        "lng" : 29.0216118
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "22 m",
                        "value" : 22
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 dakika",
                        "value" : 25
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.9863897,
                        "lng" : 29.0218105
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "\u003cb\u003eTuğlacı Eminbey Cd.\u003c/b\u003e yönünde \u003cb\u003esola\u003c/b\u003e dönün",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "mddyFahcpDNg@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.9864708,
                        "lng" : 29.0216118
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                  }
               ],
               "traffic_speed_entry" : [],
               "via_waypoint" : []
            }
         ],
         "overview_polyline" : {
            "points" : "kvdyFkqdpDUEM`B{@hHQfBGXMZ@Lc@lAQj@Sj@HFHF^X?D?B@@DBDABAhAz@bErCHRJHd@`@n@~@BDHKlAzBJXD\\ZD`@DVADA@DDNJERCVAbAJNg@"
         },
         "summary" : "Serasker Cd. ve Mühürdar Cd.",
         "warnings" : [
            "Yürüyerek gitmek için yol tarifi beta özelliğinde mevcuttur. Dikkat – Bu rotada kaldırım veya yaya yolu olmayabilir."
         ],
         "waypoint_order" : []
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I do not prefer to deserialize the whole object as service is not going to use nearly all these properties except `"legs"`, `"steps"`, and `"end_location"` which is inside of `"steps"`.

Comment: *"I do not prefer to deserialize the whole object"* - You're making it more difficult than it has to be. `JObject.Parse(content)` is deserializing the whole thing already. Just traverse the object graph instead of converting back to string and reparsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem** is that your code to query selected portions of the `JObject obj` hierarchy repeatedly converts back and forth from `JToken` to JSON string representations, and at one point, rather than *re-parsing* a JSON string, you simply use it as a *string literal*.

Specifically, the problem is with the following code:

```
JArray legArray = new JArray();
foreach (JObject item in routeArray)
{
    string leg = item.GetValue("legs").ToString();
    legArray.Add(leg);
}
```

You are calling [`JArray.Add()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Add.htm), but this method has multiple overloads, so which one is called?  Because there is an [implicit operator from `string` to `JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Implicit_29.htm), what happens is that the `leg` string gets converted to a `JValue` string literal using the implicit operator, which in turn is added to the `JArray`.  Afterwards the following code fails with an invalid cast exception, since the items you added to `legArray` are of type `JValue` not `JObject`:

```
foreach (JObject item in legArray)
{
```

**The solution** is to simplify your code and completely avoid converting back and forth between `string` and `JToken` representations.  The following code does the trick:

```
var endLocationList = obj
    .SelectTokens("routes[*].legs[*].steps[*].end_location")
    .Select(t => t.ToObject<Location>())
    .ToList();
```

Using the type

```
public class Location
{
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lng { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- You can deserialize directly from a `JToken` to a POCO using [`JToken.ToObject<T>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm).  This is simpler and more performant that formatting the `JToken` as a string then deserializing the string.
- [`JToken.SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) allows for querying the JSON hierarchy using [JSONPath syntax](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm).

  Here `[*]` represents a wildcard selecting all items in an array, specifically the `"routes"`, `"legs"` and `"steps"` arrays.

  For further information see [# JSONPath - XPath for JSON](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dHECZs).

Comment: this works perfectly on my local machine and my return model is like this `[{"Legs":[{"Steps":[{"EndLocation":[{"Lat":41.0917854,"Lng":29.0938952},{"Lat":41.0927256,"Lng":29.0943774},{"Lat":41.0931956,"Lng":29.094848},{"Lat":41.094488299999988,"Lng":29.0952805},{"Lat":41.0945246,"Lng":29.0954362},{"Lat":41.0945706,"Lng":29.0955857},{"Lat":41.094365499999988,"Lng":29.0967187}]}]}]}]` But, after I publish this API project to server and send the very same request to the method which returns this model, it returns the model without filling the EndLocation list

Comment: Live project returns this: `[{"Legs":[{"Steps":[{"EndLocation":[]}]}]}]` The strange part is, I have also tested on a different server, and it fills the model as intended. Do you have any idea how this could be happening?

Comment: @RaZzLe - need to see a [mcve] but maybe you're not configuring your server to use camel case?  See maybe [How can I return camelCase JSON serialized by JSON.NET from ASP.NET MVC controller methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19445730/3744182) or [asp.net core 1.0 web api use camelcase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38139607/3744182).