# Request/Response will be converted to different naming conventions, without my knowledge/willing

Tags: c#, json, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

First I write it a little bit general, if you need more informations, tell me!

My C#-Class looks like this, when sent/received on the frontend:

```
    public class Recipe : ICRUD
    {       
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public Guid UnitID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        // ... plus Lists ...
    }
```

**[Backend => Frontend]**

*Backend*

```
 [HttpGet("Recipe/[action]")]
 public async Task<JsonResult> GetRecipes(ServerRequest filter)
```

*Frontend*

```
   getRecipes(filter: ServerRequest) {
        return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'Recipe/GetRecipes' + '?' + this.toQueryString(filter))
            .pipe(map((res: Recipe[]) => { return res; }));
    }
```

I was looking at my network traffic and(something)changed the model:

```
ID => id
UnitID => unitId 
// ... plus Lists ...
```

So I changed my (frontend, typescript) model as well:

```
export class Recipe {
    id: string;
    unitId: string;
    title: string; 
}
```

Now finally I got a stable state, and I want to sent the data back to the server.

*Next problem:*

**[Frontend => Backend]**

*Frontend*

```
createRecipe(recipe: Recipe) {
        return this._http.post(this.myAppUrl + 'Recipe/CreateRecipe', recipe)
            .pipe(map(res => { return res; }));
```

*Backend*

```
[HttpPost("Recipe/[action]")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateRecipe([FromBody]Recipe recipe)
```

Guess what ?

`ModelState` is invalid, because he is missing `UnitID`, yeah, because it's written like this `unitId`

He is expecting capital letter(...`UnitID`..), but I am sending `unitId`, then `UnitID` is `null`(at least this is my explaination) ?

What shall I do ?

Comment: Change the backend, fields are usually not written in lowerCamelCase

Comment: they are still like this,(`  public class Recipe : ICRUD
    {       
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public Guid UnitID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        // ... plus Lists ...
    }`) only frontend object is like lowercase(almost)

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to say -not-. I did mean they should be written in lowerCamelCase

Comment: it should be `unitID` and you don't need to change your back end.

Comment: The capital D is the problem. The back end should be `UnitId` that would be the standard convention

Comment: I think asp.net-core camel cases by default, see [asp.net core 1.0 web api use camelcase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38139607) for how to disable.  Or if you are using asp.net-core 3.0 see [ASP.NET Core 3.0 System.Text.Json Camel Case Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58476681), because 3.0 uses a new serializer by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "thing" that is converting your data without your knowledge is the JSON serializer. In ASP.NET Core the default JSON serializer will convert pascal cased C# types into camel cased JSON. E.g. given this C# class

```
class Recipe
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid UnitID { get; set; }
}
```

an instance will be converted to this JSON:

```
{
    "id": "...",
    "unitID": "..."
}
```

The reverse process happens when binding JSON to a C# class. Notice how the two occurrences of "id" are different.

You have several options:

- You can use the default JSON serializer which maps to camel case and adjust your front-end code match the JSON this results in.
- You can do same with a slight twist: Change "ID" to "Id" in C#. This will be less confusing because your JSON properties will then be `id` and `unitId`.
- Decorate the properties on the C# class with attributes like `[JsonProperty]` (when using Json.NET) or `[JsonPropertyName]` (when using `System.Text.Json`) to take full control over how they they will be named in JSON.
- You can configure the JSON serializer to not convert to camel case. The JSON property names will then match the C# property names. How you configure the JSON serializer depends on the version of ASP.NET Core you are using. This was changed in ASP.NET Core 3 where Json.NET was replaced by `System.Text.Json`.

In case you are using ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 you can configure the Json.NET serializer used in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        // Other changes to options.SerializerSettings ...
    });
```

Here I'm setting the contract resolver back to the default instead of the camel case version (`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`).