# Getting the JsonPropertyAttribute of a Property

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, properties, json.net

I found a post with a great answer for a problem I have, but I can't seem to find a small detail I'm looking for.

```
public class myModel
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
   public long ID { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "some_string")]
   public string SomeString {get; set;} 
}
```

I need a method which returns the `JsonProperty` `PropertyName` of a specific property. Maybe something where I can pass the `Type` and the `Property` I need, and the method returns the value if found.

Here's the method I found which has me in the right direction (I believe) [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33616653/286618)

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...

public static string GetFields(Type modelType)
{
    return string.Join(",",
        modelType.GetProperties()
                 .Select(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>()
                 .Where(jp => jp != null)
                 .Select(jp => jp.PropertyName));
}
```

The goal is to call a function like this (any modification is fine)

```
string field = GetField(myModel, myModel.ID);
```

**Update #1**

I modified the above to this, but I don't know how to get the string of `ID` from `myModel.ID`.

```
public static string GetFields(Type modelType, string field) {
    return string.Join(",",
        modelType.GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.Name == field)
            .Select(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>())
            .Where(jp => jp != null)
            .Select(jp => jp.PropertyName)
        );
}
```

I want to **prevent** hard-coding strings of actual property names. For example I **do not** want to call the above method as:

```
string field = GetField(myModel, "ID");
```

I would rather use something like

```
string field = GetField(myModel, myModel.ID.PropertyName);
```

But I'm not entirely sure how to properly do this.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637679/reflection-get-attribute-name-and-value-on-property

Comment: It shouldn't matter that it's a json attribute, the above should still work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reflection - get attribute name and value on property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637679/reflection-get-attribute-name-and-value-on-property)

Comment: @demo I got it to work with strings, but how do I get `ID` from `myModel.ID` i'm not familiar with `Reflection` if it even has anything to do with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @twoleggedhorse I think my problem is more in terms of how to prevent myself or other users from hard-coding a `string` to represent the property `myModel.ID`

Comment: @demo see update #1, I kinda did that already, but how do I prevent hard-coding a string. I'd prefer to use something like `string field = GetField(myModel, myModel.ID.PropertyName());` I hope this helps understand my issues better

Comment: what about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35095504/3917754 ?

Comment: @demo that's funny I was just looking at that one. But since this class is not static, how can I use something like this without instantiating an object? Is that even possible? Sorry for my ignorance. I guess I'm learning as I go here too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it while keeping things strongly typed:

```
public static string GetPropertyAttribute<TType>(Expression<Func<TType, object>> property)
{
    var memberExpression = property.Body as MemberExpression;
    if(memberExpression == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Expression must be a property");

    return memberExpression.Member
        .GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>()
        .PropertyName;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var result = GetPropertyAttribute<myModel>(t => t.SomeString);
```

You can make this a bit more generic, for example:

```
public static TAttribute GetPropertyAttribute<TType, TAttribute>(Expression<Func<TType, object>> property)
where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    var memberExpression = property.Body as MemberExpression;
    if(memberExpression == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Expression must be a property");

    return memberExpression.Member
        .GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>();
}
```

And now because the attribute is generic, you need to move the `PropertyName` call outside:

```
var attribute = GetPropertyAttribute<myModel, JsonPropertyAttribute>(t => t.SomeString);
var result = attribute.PropertyName;
```

Comment: You are awesome! I had just found a very similar answer that gave me the `MemberExpression` and stuff. Thank you. It works as desired.

Comment: I've simplified it, dunno why I didn't do it this way in the first place!

Comment: nice! Thanks! I see you can from a VB6 background like me =) I was away during the .Net intro era, and sometimes I wish I knew so much more than I I think I do. =)

Comment: thanks for the `null` checking, I was just about to mention it.

Comment: DavidG, for future things I may need/use, how can I make `JSonPropertyAttribute` a generic type that I can pass to the method?

Comment: David, I just ran this against my class and it errors out with `null exception` when a property does not have a `JsonPropertyAttribute`

Comment: The generic version in the edit would help with that. Check if the return from this is `null`. Or even use null propogation check: `var result = GetPropertyAttribute(..)?.PropertyName;`

Comment: thanks! changed it a bit for my liking but works great!

Comment: Minor improvement with pattern matching:

`if (!(property.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression)) throw new ArgumentException("Expression must be a property");`

Comment: Hmm not sure why but this example didn't work for me for property types others than string.