# How do I use the generated JsonProperty Name = name from JSON file to access a single element in a corresponding C# Class

Tags: c#, json.net

How do I use the (generated) JsonProperty  Name = name from JSON file to access a single element in a corresponding C# Class?
Here is what I am trying to do …

I have a Xamarin “classic” Newtonsoft  application where I load a JSON file into a C# class `MagicTime`.

Here is the first part of my class  - This was generated automatically by the newtonsoft web site using my JSON file

```
public partial class MagicTime
{
    [JsonProperty("Accel Delay")]
    public long AccelDelay { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Accel Period")]
    public long AccelPeriod { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Alt DT Step")]
    public long AltDtStep { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Beep On Command")]
    public bool BeepOnCommand { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Bunt Step")]
    public long BuntStep { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Bunt Timeout")]
```

This is how load/deserialize an instant where loadp is string variable containing the contents of the JSON file

```
MagicTime MT = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MagicTime>(loadp );
```

This works fine
In the application I modify the values of some data element e.g 
Looking at the above – MT.AccelDelay = 21;

I then reverse the process and write /Serialize I out

That work too.

Now I have an new requirement to use the JsonProperty name to access the corresponding C# data item

It the example above I want to use `[JsonProperty("Accel Delay")]` to access the corresponding c# element `MT.AccelDelay`.

I have seen examples where a JSON string is loaded into  `JObject` to do this but not my case where is no (that I can see) `JObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Newtonsoft's [`ContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) for this purpose, as it defines how Json.NET maps from c# objects to JSON objects.

First, define the following extension method:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    static readonly IContractResolver defaultResolver = new JsonSerializer().ContractResolver;

    public static T GetJsonPropertyValue<T>(object obj, string propertyName, IContractResolver resolver = null)
    {
        resolver = resolver ?? defaultResolver;
        var contract = resolver.ResolveContract(obj.GetType());
        if (contract is JsonObjectContract objectContract)
        {
            var property = objectContract.Properties.GetClosestMatchProperty(propertyName);
            if (property == null)
                throw new JsonException(string.Format("Unknown property {0}", propertyName));
            return (T)property.ValueProvider.GetValue(obj);
        }
        throw new JsonException(string.Format("Invalid contract {0}", contract));
    }
}
```

And now you can do:

```
var accelDelay = JsonExtensions.GetJsonPropertyValue<long>(MT, "Accel Delay");
```

If you don't know the type in advance, you can just do:

```
var accelDelay = JsonExtensions.GetJsonPropertyValue<object>(MT, "Accel Delay");
```

And if you are using camel casing, do:

```
var resolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
var accelDelay = JsonExtensions.GetJsonPropertyValue<object>(MT, "Accel Delay", resolver);
```

Notes:

- If the incoming `obj` maps to something other than a JSON object (e.g. an array or primitive) then `GetJsonPropertyValue()` will throw an exception.  It will also throw if the property is set-only.
- If you need a way to discover all the JSON property names for a given type, see *[Get a list of JSON property names from a class to use in a query string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33616005/3744182)*, especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45829514/3744182).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hz4SpB).

Comment: Thanks very much , that answers my question , I needed to set the value too but it was not hard to do a corresponding SetValue methos to go with this GetValue