# How to get Json Property name using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, json.net, system.reflection

I have a class as mentioned below:

```
public class Employee {

    [JsonProperty("emp_id")]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("emp_fname")]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("emp_lname")]
    public string LastName {get;set;} 
}
```

In the above class, I have assigned Newtonsoft Attribute for serialization.

I have a object of class `Employee` and Now I would like to find the property by `JsonProperty` and get value of that property.

For example, I would like to get the value of the property for which JsonProprty attribute name is set to `emp_lname`

Is there a way to find value like this using reflection?

Comment: I believe the JsonProperty tags are used for deserialization of a string. Within your code, if you have the Json deserialized, you would use `Name` instead of `emp_fname` to access the value.

Comment: `var pInfo = [EmployeeInstance].GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetCustomAttributes<JsonPropertyAttribute>().Any(at => at.PropertyName.Equals("emp_lname")));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Json.NET's own [contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) for this purpose.  Doing so will correctly handle properties with, and without, `[JsonProperty(string name)]` attributes added, as well as objects with [naming strategies](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_NamingStrategyType.htm) or [data contract attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm) applied directly.

First add the following method:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    static readonly IContractResolver defaultResolver = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().ContractResolver;

    public static object GetJsonProperty<T>(T obj, string jsonName, bool exact = false, IContractResolver resolver = null)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
        resolver = resolver ?? defaultResolver;
        var contract = resolver.ResolveContract(obj.GetType()) as JsonObjectContract;
        if (contract == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is not serialized as a JSON object", obj));
        var property = contract.Properties.GetProperty(jsonName, exact ? StringComparison.Ordinal : StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (property == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Property {0} was not found.", jsonName));
        return property.ValueProvider.GetValue(obj); // Maybe check JsonProperty.Readable first, and throw an exception if not?
    }
}
```

And now you can do:

```
var employee = new Employee
{
    LastName = "last name",
};

Console.WriteLine("Value of {0} is {1}.", "emp_lname", 
                  JsonExtensions.GetJsonProperty(employee, "emp_lname")); // Prints Value of emp_lname is last name.
```

If your app uses camel casing for JSON serialization by default, you can pass a [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm) in for `resolver` like so:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value of {0} is {1}.", "emp_lname", 
                  JsonExtensions.GetJsonProperty(employee, "emp_lname", resolver : new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()));
```

If you need to get a list of all JSON property names for a given type, see *[Get a list of JSON property names from a class to use in a query string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33616005/3744182)*:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static string [] PropertyNames(Type type)
    {
        return PropertyNames(defaultResolver, type);
    }

    //Taken from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45829514/3744182
    //To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616005/get-a-list-of-json-property-names-from-a-class-to-use-in-a-query-string
    public static string [] PropertyNames(this IContractResolver resolver, Type type)
    {
        if (resolver == null || type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var contract = resolver.ResolveContract(type) as JsonObjectContract;
        if (contract == null)
            return new string[0];
        return contract.Properties.Where(p => !p.Ignored).Select(p => p.PropertyName).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0KVTk4).